# Building VS 2012 c++ projects in VS 2015

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I have a couple of VS 2012 C++ projects in the VS 2015 solution. In order to build the solution I need to have VS 2012 installed as well else the projects will fail to build. 
I am evaluating if it possible to do away with the installation of VS 2012 and instead get the toolset for VS 2012. Upgrading these projects to VS 2015 is not an option at the moment. 
I was exploring Windows SDK but it looks like from 2012 onwards Microsoft is no longer shipping the command-line build environment.

Can anyone help me with the available options?